# for cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to make a loop from a list based in a class, but im receiving this error :
for cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'

the point is, do a list (this list must it have a 1 class) for to register in the list the names and qualifications of students. but in the loop this not working good
(the text in black cursive is actually in red in my code)

```
public  class Register
{
    public string Name{ set; get; }
    public int Note{ set; get; }


    public string ask()
    {
        List<Register> Students = new List<Register>();
        var student= new Register();

        string question;
        var r1 = "si";
        Console.WriteLine("Desea agregar un estudiante? ");
        question= Console.ReadLine();

        while(question == r1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cual es el nombre del estudiante?: ");
            student.Name= Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Cual es la nota del estudiante?: ");
            student.Note = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Students.Add(student);

            Console.WriteLine("Desea agregargar otro estudiante?: ");

            question = Console.ReadLine();

        }
        for (int i = 1; i < Students.Count; i++)
        {
            if (***student.Note[i]*** >= 70)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{***student.Name[i]***} ha aprobado con {***student.Note[i]***}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{***student.Name[i]***} ha reprobado con {***alumno.Nota[i]***}");
            }
        }

        return Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, the stars are for the red code in the visual studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Students is the list. Note is a property of the Register objects in that list. Therefore in order to access a specific element of the Students list, you need to use the indexer on it, not the property. So it would look like this:

```
if (Students[i].Note >= 70)
{
    ....
```

Similarly the Console.WriteLine statements would also need to use Students[i].Name instead of student, which was a single object.

Comment: thank, just one thing more, i do what u are recommending but in the result i have the laste name registered, and repeat it the many times you add new student, you have any idea?

Comment: You are using the same instance of student each time you ask the question, so you are just adding the same object to the list over and over. When you set the properties, you are just changing the properties on that same instance. You want to create a new instance each time. So move the var student= new Register(); to inside of your while loop.

Comment: bro, you are amazing!, thanx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`student.Name[i]` should be `student[i].Name`.

```
if (student[i].Note >= 70)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{student[i].Name} ha aprobado con {student[i].Note}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{student[i].Name} ha reprobado con {alumno[i].Nota}");
}
```

Comment: Should be Students with upper case since that is the variable defined as the array. Lower case student was just a single instance, so you would get the same error.

Comment: You are right. I Just copy the original code and don't test it

Comment: I think students is better than studentList

Comment: You are right. I misread. I withdrew my previous comment. :-)

Comment: Although I think 's' is better than 'list' but sometime I still use xxxList in my code anyway